What Nikon bodies support SnapBridge and recent F-mount lenses?
I have a Nikon D3000 and several auto focus capable lenses. I am looking to upgrade my camera to another Nikon but something newer that has Snapbridge and will work with my auto focus lenses. Anyone know of a newer camera body style that will fulfill both requests?

The following Nikon cameras support SnapBridge:



Camera
Mount
FX/DX




Z 9
Z
FX


Z 8
Z
FX


Z 7II
Z
FX


Z 7
Z
FX


Z 6II
Z
FX


Z 6
Z
FX


Z 5
Z
FX


Z f
Z
FX


Z fc
Z
DX


Z 50
Z
DX


Z 30
Z
DX


D6
F
FX


D850
F
FX


D780
F
FX


D500
F
FX


D7500
F
FX


D5600
F
FX


D3500
F
FX


D3400
F
FX



All of the F-mount bodies (D6–D3400) will support the lenses you currently have without any problem. Your lenses (assuming they're DX lenses) can be used on the F-mount FX bodies (D6-D780), but will use the center 44% of the camera's sensor, because DX lenses (so-called 'crop lenses') project a
smaller image circle than full-frame (FX) lenses. These FX bodies will automatically detect DX lenses and save appropriately cropped images; there's nothing you have to do when mounting the lenses, or in post-processing).
All of the Z cameras use the Nikon Z-mount. You need to use the Nikon F to Z adapter to use your existing lenses on a Z-mount camera. The same FX/DX considerations apply when using your lenses on a Z camera + F-to-Z adapter.

Where did you get the 63% number? Is that linear or areal? It's my understanding that crop mode on FX Nikon DSLRs are 67% linear, which translates to 45% in terms of image area. Canon is 62.5% and 39%.

@MichaelC Nikon crop is 1.6. So 1/1.6 = 0.625 ≈ 63%. You're right, I should have squared the 1.6. I don't know why I had 1.6 in my head. I know it's 1.5. Having a brain fog day, I guess.
